# Looking for non-domestic building floor areas in Scotland

Tags: data-request, uk

Is there an equivalent of the [Valuation Office Agency Rating List](https://voaratinglists.blob.core.windows.net/html/rlidata.htm) for Scotland? I've looked on the SAA website, but can only find a way to download rateable values for individual properties. No floor area, no bulk download.